# Mock nested AWS Lambda function using Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

Ie have a unit to test:

```
import { Lambda } from 'aws-sdk'

export const handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  ctx: Context,
  cb: APIGatewayProxyCallback
): Promise<void> => {
  
  const lambda = new Lambda()
  await lambda.invoke(params).promise()
}
```

How to mock that function call in jest - await lambda.invoke(params).promise() ? For example, I simply want it to be resolved or 'skipped'.

I did try jest.spyOn without success.

Comment: Have you tried mocking the Lambda class: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks

Comment: Yes, and it's always an issue with '.promise()' on the end. Without that there would be no problem to mock.

Comment: The solution is along of the lines of mocking the invoke method to return an object that contains a function called 'promise'. This function returns a resolved promise.